# Django subir solo la data de un archivo

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Estoy trabajando en la interfaz de administrado de Django, he intentado de diferentes maneras de popular unas tablas con archivos `xls`, `csv` o `txt` sin exito, yo se como subir un archivo pero no se solo usar la data, o en su defecto que suba el archivo y que luego o durante le proceso envié la data para la base de datos. ¿ alguna idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Hola primero asegúrate de que el archivo se este subiendo, ahora bien puedes leer el contenido de un `csv` por ejemplo de la siguiente manera:

```
if request.FILES and request.POST:
    csvfile = request.FILES.get('filename', None)
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
```

para un archivo de texto seria:

```
f = codecs.open(request.FILES['filename'], encoding = 'utf-8')
data = f.readlines()
```